# Pinax Django Photologue - Moderation

Tags: django, pinax

I'm building a site for the local cub scouts using Pinax. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how we can moderate photos before they are uploaded?

Comment: moderate photos? Do you want to make sure they're of a certain type? Are you trying to filter out bad pictures? Resize?
More info please.

Comment: Thanks for replying. We just want to check photos to make sure that they are appropriate fro the site. It looks like django-gatekeeper might be just the thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean you only want to display approved photos then [django-gatekeeper](http://github.com/sunlightlabs/django-gatekeeper) is a good option. You simply register the `Image` model

```
gatekeeper.register(Image)
```

and it will add a generic relationship which includes various moderation fields. The main one being the `moderation_status` one which can be

- Approved
- Pending
- Rejected

By default when a new `Image` is created it will be set to pending status and visible for approval in the moderation queue view that is included.

When you want to display the approved images, instead of simply `Image.objects.all()`, gatekeeper adds a few extra methods to access objects with the various statuses. So to access the approved, pending, and rejected objects you would use respectively.

```
Image.objects.all().approved()
Image.objects.all().pending()
Image.objects.all().rejected()
```

I haven't tested pinax out but I've dropped gatekeeper into my own sites without changing the apps it was being used in and without any problems.